# Execute multiple sage commands from php script

Tags: php, latex, sage

I have installed Sage math on my ubuntu server. I can run sage commands by ssh terminal such as

```
$sage:   
$sage:  f = x^2
$sage:  f.diff(x)
```

I would like to do on a php script

```
exec('sage');
exec('sage: f = 5x^3');
$fprime = exec('sage: latex(f.diff(x))');

echo $fprime;
```

I would expect "15x^2" as output but that's not happening .. however on ssh terminal all is good..
all help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure of what you want to achieve. PHP's `exec` function executes a shell command, and that's all. Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php.

`sage: f = 5*x^3` is not a shell command. You can run sage scripts directly via the command line using the `-c` switch :

```
./sage -c 'print latex((5*x^3).diff())'
```

will print `15 \, x^{2}` to the terminal. In PHP you can grab this output by passing a second argument to `exec`:

```
exec("./sage -c 'print latex((5*x^3).diff())'", $output);
echo $output[0];
```

Comment: thank you so much @Luca that is exactly what I would like to do but I tried your suggestion and it does not produce the expected output it comes back blank

Comment: there is a chance it might be related to this   Error: environment variable $HOME is not set.
Error setting environment variables by sourcing './sage-env';
possibly contact sage-devel (see http://groups.google.com/group/sage-devel).

Comment: thx for your help, i got that command to work, can you please help me figure out what would the right php command be for two line commands sage: from sage.symbolic.integration.integral import indefinite_integral
sage: indefinite_integral(log(x), x)

Comment: In this case, it would be easier for you to write a small Sage script (e.g. `test.sage`) first, and then have your PHP script `exec` the Sage program.  Then you can make it as long as you want.

Comment: PS: why doesn't `integral(log(x),x)` suffice in your mini-example?

Comment: thank you very much @kcrisman you are correct and that helped me, I thought i had to load the indefinite_integral package first.. that might be required for indefinite_integral()  but it is not for integral(), I tried it and it works beautifully. Also I will implement your suggestions for longer scripts just save to a test.sage file and run the file.. thank you again

Comment: Awesome! (Extra characters.)